# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(a-1)^{-n+1}}{a^{-n-1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Hello could you please help me solve this limit?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(a-1)^{-n+1}}{a^{-n-1}},\quad a\ge1.$$

Comment: Try using the ratio test and the binomial theorem.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! The expression is not defined for $a=1$.

Comment: @LukasKofler thank you for the tip what I did was reversing the fraction so that I bring it to the type (+oo/+oo) and using De L'Hospital Rule. In the beginning I set the limit equal to some number A and tried to find A instead. I found that the limit is 0, but some say that it is infinity...what would you say?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write your term in the form $$\left(1-\frac{1}{a}\right)^{-n}a(a-1)$$

Comment: The exponent should be $-n$.

Comment: Thank you for your hint!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner thank you very much! So I suppose it is zero right?